# xslt for a date 90 days older than current date

Tags: date, xslt, date-format

I have used the following to get the current date.

```
<value><xsl:value-of select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new('dd-MM-yyyy'), java:java.util.Date.new())"/></value>
```

Now, I have a requirement where I have to get a date that is not older than 90 days from today. Please help me out to get it done using xslt?

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? XSLT 2.0 has a `xs:date` data type and operations on that type like adding or subtracting a duration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Thanks all for your responses. I have solved this issue using below code.

```
<xsl:value-of select="java:com.Utilities.getDeletedDate()" />
```

In the Utilities class i have added one method as follows.

```
public static String getDeletedDate() {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -99);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    DateFormat secondFormatter;
    String formatedDate = null;
    secondFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    formatedDate = secondFormatter.format(date);
    return formatedDate;
}
```

This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using XSLT 2.0 you can use this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P90D')"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```